# Reference Object and change it upon event

Tags: c#

I have a more theoretical question and hope you can help me out.

Imagine you have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Invalid;
    //some more Properties/Fields/Methods and stuff but only the event is important for my question
}
```

Now you have 2 more classes one that initialize this object and works with it the other that "watches" the object and does some other stuff:

```
public class Bar
{
    private Foo _foo;
    public void Main()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
        FooUtils.RegisterFoo(_foo);

        //do some stuff with foo...
    }
}

public static class FooUtils
{
    public static void RegisterFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.Invalid -= OnInvalid;
        foo.Invalid += OnInvalid;
    }

    private static void OnInvalid(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var foo = sender as Foo;
        if (foo != null)
        {
            //do some stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

I want to extend the FooUtils that in some occasions it can create a new instance of Foo, so I tought "Hey no problem just pass it on as reference.", so I change the code to the following...

```
public class Bar
{
    private Foo _foo;
    public void Main()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
        //do some stuff with foo...

        FooUtils.RegisterFoo(ref _foo);
    }
}

public static class FooUtils
{
    public static void RegisterFoo(ref Foo foo)
    {
        foo.Invalid -= OnInvalid;
        foo.Invalid += OnInvalid;
    }

    private static void OnInvalid(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var foo = sender as Foo;
        if (foo != null)
        {
            //do some stuff...

            //create a new Instance and set it to ?!?
            var helpMe = new Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

This code would work if I would instance a new Foo inside the Register method but I need to create a new instance inside the event (on line `var helpMe = new Foo();),` how would I do that? So that in the end the field _foo inside Bar gets updated? Please keep in mind that I could Register several Foos in the **static** FooUtils and depending what registered Foo fires the Invalid event the corresponding reference should get updated. Is that even possible, if not what would be an good alternative?

Just to make sure: Yes, I know I could listen to the event inside Bar and just set the _foo field inside bar itself but if possible I would like to keep this separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    private Foo _foo;
    public void Main()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
        //do some stuff with foo...

        FooUtils.RegisterFoo(_foo, ReferenceChanger);
    }

    public void ReferenceChanger (Foo anotherFoo)
    {
        _foo = anotherFoo;
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler Invalid;
    //some more Properties/Fields/Methods and stuff but only the event is important for my question
}

public static class FooUtils
{
    private static Dictionary<Foo, Action<Foo>> actionsToCallDictionary;
    public static void RegisterFoo( Foo foo, Action<Foo> changeReferenceAction)
    {
        foo.Invalid -= OnInvalid;

        if (actionsToCallDictionary != null)
            actionsToCallDictionary.Remove(foo);

        foo.Invalid += OnInvalid;

        if (actionsToCallDictionary == null)
            actionsToCallDictionary = new Dictionary<Foo, Action<Foo>>();

        actionsToCallDictionary[foo] = changeReferenceAction;

    }

    private static void OnInvalid(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var foo = sender as Foo;
        if (foo != null)
        {
            //do some stuff...

            //create a new Instance and set it to ?!?
            Action<Foo> referenceChanger;
            if (actionsToCallDictionary != null && actionsToCallDictionary.TryGetValue(foo, out referenceChanger))
            {
                var changeWith = new Foo();
                referenceChanger(changeWith);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But be aware that you could end with memory leaks if you don't carefully dispose / manage that static dictionary.

Another issue would be in a multithreading environment where you should lock / unlock on that dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your `EventHandler` inside your `Foo` class with delegate pointing to method where sender is passed by reference:

```
public class Foo
{
    public delegate void InvalidEventHandler(ref Foo sender, EventArgs args);
    public event InvalidEventHandler Invalid;
}
```

Then you need to change your `OnInvalid` method:

```
private static void OnInvalid(ref Foo sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        //do some stuff...

        sender = new Foo();
    }
}
```

Now, when invoking that method, you'll need to pass `Foo` by reference and changes will be visible to your `Foo` object inside `Boo` class.

Comment: Can I really call the Event with `ref this`, since I would have an event invoker inside Foo like `protected virtual InvokeInvalidEvent() { var handler = this.Invalid; if (handler != null) { handler(ref this, EventArgs.Empty); } }` don't have an IDE here so I am asking instead of trying.

Comment: No, you can't call handler that way. But why would you keep your OnInvalid method inside FooUtils if you're calling it from the object itself. It just makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe I am missing the big picture here, but its an event of the Foo itself and I can fire it only inside of Foo, or I would get the message saying something like "You can only write the event followed by += or -=." so with your solution I could only make an public event invoker and pass the object inside, but the object it self could fire the event it self. Isn't it normal that events get fired from within the object itself, why would I fire the event from outside and do logic outside of the object? FooUtils just listens to the event and does things accordingly. Am I wrong, if so pls tell.

Comment: Well you can invoke the event from Foo object itself, but if so, why don't you make the changes to it after invoking the event. You could also pass reference of foo to the foo object itself when calling the method from whom you'll invoke the event eventually. Like _foo.DoSomething(ref foo); I don't have the whole picture so I might be wrong on many levels.